# htaccess and php routing

Tags: php, .htaccess

I was learning today about Rewrite and PHP routing. I wrote the following .htaccess file:

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^(.+)$ testing.php?url=$1 [NC,L]
```

The testing.php has the following code:

```
    <?php
       echo $_GET["url"];
    ?>
```

When I enter the following URL for example: http://localhost/tests/Hello
The following is shown in the browser:

```
     testing.php
```

But I am expecting "Hello" to show instead of "testing.php". I tried to change NC to QSA and it worked successfully but why the first case is not working?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's likely that the URL is being rewritten more than once.

The first time rewrites `/Hello` to `testing.php` but then internally a separate request is made to `testing.php` and ran through the rewrite engine again. That will give you `testing.php` as the URL parameter.

Using `QSA` means that on the second request it is appending to the query string as opposed to overwriting it. If you looked at `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` you would likely see something like `url=testing.php&url=Hello` (or similar) and php is just using the last value in `url`.

Using `NC` is not necessary as the pattern you are using has no case (`.+` matches one or more of any character regardless of case).

Using `L` means to stop processing rules in this request, but doesn't stop processing rules in subsequent requests (including transparent/internal subsequent requests).

Usually this is fixed by telling mod_rewrite to ignore the request if it is made to a file that exists using a `RewriteCond` like:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ testing.php?url=$1
```

Which tells apache that if the requested filename is not a file and not a directory, process the rule. With this in place, the request to `testing.php` will see the file exists, condition fails and so the rule isn't processed additional times. Nothing would stop additional rules from applying though if they exist. And also, just an FYI, conds only apply to the very next rule. So if you multiple rules, you need these cond for each of them.

Comment: Thank you Jonathan. Your answer was great but what is the reason behind the second request?

Comment: go read the documentation for the `[L]` flag at: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_l It has to do with how mod_rewrite and apache processes requests. When rewrite is done parsing rules, it returns control back to the URL parsing engine which could in turn have some rule/redirect (internal or external) that causes it to process the rules again.

Answer (score 0):

QSA stands for Query-String-Append, which means that the Query string that was first sent gets appended. With NC, you were only doing `nocase`, meaning that the RewriteRule will be matched in a case-insensitive manner.

L just means that RewriteRule will stop processing it after that rule.